# Aligning view to a moving anchor view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a simple menu for game. When the player taps an option, the list of options move to one side, making space for a sub-menu to fade in.

`gameModeChoose` is containing the options that move to the side after an option is chosen, and `subMenu` is the sub-menu that fades in (created programmatically). To align the sub-menu to the right the list of options, I'm using `subMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.game_mode_choose)` and `mainFrame.addView(subMenu,subMenuParams)`, however this aligns the sub-menu to where ever the list of options were **before** it moved to make space for the sub-menu. I suspect that the problem might be happening because I'm using `gameModeChoose.animate().translationXBy(...)` to move the list of option, but I don't know how to debug it. I've tried using `addRule(...)` after the list of options moves and also tried using `subMenu.setLayoutParams(...)` to try to update the view, but none of these things work.

The problem I described happens in the `onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)` methods that I placed comments in.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1plyr;
    Button btn2plyr;
    RelativeLayout gameModeChoose;
    RelativeLayout subMenu;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams subMenuParams;
    int menuState;
    ImageButton circle;
    ImageButton cross;
    TextView hint;
    RelativeLayout mainFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menuState = 0;
        btn1plyr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1Plyr);
        btn2plyr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2Plyr);
        gameModeChoose = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_mode_choose);
        hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu_hint);
        subMenu = new RelativeLayout (this);
        subMenuParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
        circle = new ImageButton(this);
        cross = new ImageButton(this);
        mainFrame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        subMenu.setAlpha(0);
        subMenu.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title_border));
        subMenuParams.leftMargin = 10;
        subMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.game_mode_choose);
        subMenuParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,R.id.game_mode_choose);
        subMenuParams.height = 400;
        subMenuParams.width = 150;




        btn1plyr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(menuState == 0) {
                    gameModeChoose.animate().translationXBy(-150f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            //here
                            Log.d("coords", "x:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getX()) + " y:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getY()));
                            mainFrame.addView(subMenu,subMenuParams);
                            subMenu.animate().alpha(1f);
                            hint.setText("Choose : O's go first.");

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });

                    menuState = 1;


                } else if(menuState == 1 || menuState == 2){
                    subMenu.animate().alpha(0);
                    MainActivity.this.gameModeChoose.animate().translationXBy(150f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            hint.setText("Choose a game mode:");
                            Log.d("coords", "x:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getX()) + " y:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getY()));
                            mainFrame.removeView(subMenu);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            hint.setText("Choose a game mode:");
                            mainFrame.removeView(subMenu);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });

                    menuState = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        btn2plyr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(menuState == 0) {
                    gameModeChoose.animate().translationXBy(-150f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            //here
                            Log.d("coords", "x:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getX()) + " y:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getY()));
                            subMenu.setLayoutParams(subMenuParams);
                            mainFrame.addView(subMenu);
                            subMenu.animate().alpha(1f);
                            hint.setText("Choose : O's go first.");
                            menuState = 2;

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });

                } else if(menuState == 2 || menuState == 1){
                    subMenu.animate().alpha(0);
                    MainActivity.this.gameModeChoose.animate().translationXBy(150f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            hint.setText("Choose a game mode:");
                            Log.d("coords", "x:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getX()) + " y:" + String.valueOf(gameModeChoose.getY()));
                            mainFrame.removeView(subMenu);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    });

                    menuState = 0;                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.darkjava.tictactoe.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/game_mode_choose"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1Plyr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="1 PLAYER"
            android:background="@drawable/title_border"
            android:textColor="@color/title">

        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2Plyr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="2 PLAYER"
            android:background="@drawable/title_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn1Plyr">

        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menu_hint"
        android:text="Choose a game mode:"
        android:layout_above="@+id/game_mode_choose"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#464646"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TIC TAC TOE"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Relative layouts align views based on their permanent position, not based on the temporary translated position.  The easiest fix would likely to be to translate both menus by the same amount, or to put them in a common parent and translate the parent.

Comment: If they align based on their permanent position, and I could somehow get the position of `gameModeChoose` relative to another anchor with margins, I could then use the `LayoutParams` of `gameModeChoose` to do `gameModeChooseParams.setMargins(...)` and set the alignment  rules with `addRule(...)`. This would make it's position "permanent" correct? I probably will use your solution, just curious...